# Scala using shapeless to combine higher kinded coproducts over a natural transformation

Tags: scala, shapeless, higher-kinded-types

Given a set of Adts which have two distinct sub sets
For example:

```
sealed trait Domain[Y]
sealed trait Command[Y] extends Domain[Y]
sealed trait Query[Y] extends Domain[Y]

case class Add(value:String) extends Command[Ack]
case class Remove(value:String) extends Command[Ack]
case class Exists(value:String) extends Query[Boolean]
case object List extends Query[List[String]]
```

Now suppose I have two Natural transformations, for some arbitrary Monad M[_]:

```
val commandHandler:Command ~> M
val queryExecutor:Query ~> M
```

I wish to somehow combine these two natural transformations into a single transformation:

```
val service:Domain ~> M = union(commandHandler, queryExecutor)
```

However we are struggling to get off the starting block with having higherkinded coproducts.  Even a point in the right direction would be helpful at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is a very old question, but nowadays, cats for example provides `Coproduct` and a method `or` on [NaturalTransformation](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/2ee0a8a/core/src/main/scala/cats/arrow/NaturalTransformation.scala):

```
trait NaturalTransformation[F[_], G[_]] extends Serializable { self =>
  def or[H[_]](h: H ~> G): Coproduct[F, H, ?] ~> G = ???
}
```

So you could use this to do (using [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) for the type lambda `?`)

```
val combine: Coproduct[Command,Query,?] ~> M = commandHandler.or(queryExecutor)
```

---

EDIT: Here is a full example that also defines `union` (using `Id` instead of `M` for type checking):

```
import cats._
import cats.data._

trait Ack
sealed trait Domain[Y]
sealed trait Command[Y] extends Domain[Y]
sealed trait Query[Y] extends Domain[Y]

case class Add(value:String) extends Command[Ack]
case class Remove(value:String) extends Command[Ack]
case class Exists(value:String) extends Query[Boolean]
case object List extends Query[List[String]]

def commandHandler:Command ~> Id = ???
def queryExecutor:Query ~> Id = ???

def union: Domain ~> Coproduct[Command,Query,?] = new (Domain ~> Coproduct[Command,Query,?]) {
  def apply[A](fa: Domain[A]): Coproduct[Command,Query,A] = fa match {
    case command: Command[A] => Coproduct.left(command)
    case query: Query[A] => Coproduct.right(query)
  }
}

def result: Domain ~> Id = commandHandler.or(queryExecutor).compose(union)
```

or in case you want to avoid the intermediate `Coproduct`:

```
def unionDirect[M[_]](cmd: Command ~> M, qry: Query ~> M): Domain ~> M =
  new (Domain ~> M) {
    def apply[A](fa: Domain[A]): M[A] = fa match {
      case command: Command[A] => cmd(command)
      case query: Query[A] => qry(query)
    }
}

def resultDirect: Domain ~> Id = unionDirect(commandHandler,queryExecutor)
```

Comment: That certainly shifts shifts the problem to an easier place, where it needs to map a Domain -> Xor.Left[Command], or Xor.Right[Query].  That could roughly be achieved with Typetags, but taking advantage of the Adt would be better

Comment: you can easily compose another `~>` to work on the `Domain` type if you want as shown in my edit